# Makefile string comparison inside target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile

```
FIRSTARG := $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))
# use the rest as arguments
RUNARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
# ...and turn them into do-nothing targets
$(eval $(RUNARGS):;@:)


test:
    if [[ "$(FIRSTARG)" == "test" ]]; then \
        pytest --cov --cov-report term-missing ;\
    elif [[ "docker" == "$(FIRSTARG)" ]]; then \
        sudo docker run merlot:latest ;\
    fi; 

docker : $(RUNARGS)
    @echo first word: $(FIRSTARG)


.PHONY: docker build test prune
```

but I'm getting the error

```
if [[ "test" == "test" ]]; then \
    pytest --cov --cov-report term-missing ;\
elif [[ "docker" == "test" ]]; then \
    sudo docker run merlot:latest ;\
fi; 
/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
/bin/sh: 3: [[: not found
```

I have also tried using `ifeq ("test","@(FIRSTARG)")` which threw different errors. I've searched this up quite a bit but can't seem to find the proper way to compare strings inside of a target. Can you please help me get the proper way to do string comparison in a make target?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All make programs invoke `/bin/sh` which is a shell that conforms to the POSIX spec for shell scripts.  The POSIX standard doesn't define the operator `[[`, so you can't use it.

The best thing to do is use POSIX standard scripting, so just use `[` instead of `[[` and only use `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

The key clue in the error message is

```
/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
```

That is, it's `/bin/sh` complaining that the command `[[` doesn't exist.  Which is true, since there is no such command in `sh`.  This is valid syntax in `bash`, which is a generally more capable shell, but a Makefile by default executes its actions using `/bin/sh`.

It is possible to change the shell Make uses, but it's generally better to go with the flow and use sh-only syntax in actions.  Thus I suspect that, if you changed your actions to

```
if test "$(FIRSTARG)" = "test"; ...
```

(see `man test` for details) then what you have might work.

Sidenote: `[[` isn't a command in `bash` – it's built-in syntax.  There is a command `[` in both `sh` and `bash`, which is just a synonym for `test`.